# How to run a development server in Laravel Mix (standalone project)

Tags: npm, laravel-mix, npm-start

I'm trying to run a server to see my project on browser, the only way i can do it is running `npx mix watch --hot`, so after that my project start running at `localhost:8080`.

But the above command enable `hot reload`, i would like to know if there is some specific command to just run the server, without enabling `hot reloading`.

I tried `npm mix watch` but it not starts the server, just watch the files.

Tried calling manually webpack server with:

`./node_modules/.bin/webpack serve --config="./node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"`

This works (the server starts at `localhost:8080` as well) but somehow it activates `hot reloading` too, idk why.

So, there is some way to just start the server? Without enabling `hot reloading`?

Here is my `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.sass('src/scss/app.scss', 'dist/css/')
  .js('src/js/app.js', 'dist/js/').react()
  .setPublicPath('public');
```

My `package.json` has just the default script:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) you can run `php artisan serve`, this will start a local php server and serve your web pages to the browser [Laravel installation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#installation-via-composer).